# How threads are created and released in Thread pools

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have read in so many places, that Thread pools reduce the thread creation overhead which results in improved performance. But once a thread completes executing its run method, it goes to Dead/Terminated state which means it can be restarted again.

So, how does thread pool handles releasing of threads? Does it really holds the thread some way for serving next task or internally it creates new thread every time a task is submitted?

Comment: It reuses the threads it creates. That's how it reduces thread creation. It's documented, and the source code is available.

Comment: It does not release them. It keeps them on an available list when not in use.

Comment: I got it. It never allows the thread to reach the terminated state unless until its required to terminate the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Thread pool internally has list which is a place holder for threads which is being used as and when there are requirements and adds them to this list when it completes the execution or creates a new one when one terminates and maintains them by growing in number or reducing based on whether you asked for cached or fixed thread pool.

Comment: I don't see any list in source code, where the threads are added and retrieved as required and as I commented above, it looks like the threads are kept alive and whichever thread picks up the incoming task, starts working with them. Hope my understanding is correct

Comment: I am not sure where you are looking at but see [this](http://j6a.ru/classcom_1_1sun_1_1corba_1_1se_1_1impl_1_1orbutil_1_1threadpool_1_1_thread_pool_impl.html#ae115183d2b25be0185d7e6afc9d60427) for your reference. I would advice you to attach src.zip to your IDE and go over the code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed size thread pools keep the threads until shutdown.

The Cached thread pool keeps the thread for 60 seconds by default.